# combination workout in r

Tags: r, combinations

Here is my dataframe:

```
name <- c("P1", "P2", "IndA", "IndB", "IndC", "IndD", "IndE", "IndF", "IndG")
    A <- c(1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 4)
    B <- c(2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2, 2)
    mydf <- data.frame (name, A, B)
```

The following explanation illustrates what combination I want to generate and identify that is not possible combination.

Each parents (P1 and P2) has two and can contribute one to their child (Individual).

[image]

The parents can have same (for example 1, in the following example) and can contribute one each time.
[image]

Thus this becomes a combination game, the following example of combination.

[image]

Reciprocals are same (correct): 1 3 is same as 3 1

[image]

**Question is: creat possible combination and find those that can not be member of combination.**

```
   name <- c("P1", "P2", "IndA", "IndB", "IndC", "IndD", "IndE", "IndF", "IndG")
    A <- c(1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 4)
    B <- c(2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2, 2)
    mydf <- data.frame (name, A, B)

 name A B
1   P1 1 2
2   P2 3 4
3 IndA 1 3
4 IndB 2 4
5 IndC 2 2
6 IndD 5 2
7 IndE 5 6
8 IndF 1 2
9 IndG 4 2
```

[image]

**Expected output:**

```
   name A B     correct 
    1   P1 1 2   NA
    2   P2 3 4   NA
    3 IndA 1 3   TRUE
    4 IndB 2 4   TRUE
    5 IndC 2 2   FALSE
    6 IndD 5 2   FALSE
    7 IndE 5 6   FALSE
    8 IndF 1 2   FALSE
    9 IndG 4 2   TRUE
```

**Edits:** Second dataset for double check:

```
   name <- c("P1", "P2", "IndH", "IndI", "IndJ", "IndK")
    A <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3)
    B <- c(1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 5)
    mydf2 <- data.frame (name, A, B)
    mydf2
   name A B Correct 
1   P1 1 1    NA
2   P2 3 4    NA
3 IndH 3 3    FALSE
4 IndI 1 1    FALSE
5 IndJ 4 1    TRUE
6 IndK 3 5    FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
dum.match<-rbind(expand.grid(c(mydf[1,2:3]),c(mydf[2,2:3])),expand.grid(c(mydf[2,2:3]),c(mydf[1,2:3])))
newmydf<-cbind(mydf,paste(mydf$A,mydf$B)%in%paste(dum.match$Var1,dum.match$Var2))

> newmydf
  name A B paste(mydf$A, mydf$B) %in% paste(dum.match$Var1, dum.match$Var2)
1   P1 1 2                                                            FALSE
2   P2 3 4                                                            FALSE
3 IndA 1 3                                                             TRUE
4 IndB 2 4                                                             TRUE
5 IndC 2 2                                                            FALSE
6 IndD 5 2                                                            FALSE
7 IndE 5 6                                                            FALSE
8 IndF 1 2                                                            FALSE
9 IndG 4 2                                                             TRUE

dum.match2<-rbind(expand.grid(c(mydf2[1,2:3]),c(mydf2[2,2:3])),expand.grid(c(mydf2[2,2:3]),c(mydf2[1,2:3])))
newmydf2<-cbind(mydf2,paste(mydf2$A,mydf2$B)%in%paste(dum.match2$Var1,dum.match2$Var2))

> newmydf2
  name A B paste(mydf2$A, mydf2$B) %in% paste(dum.match2$Var1, dum.match2$Var2)
1   P1 1 1                                                                FALSE
2   P2 3 4                                                                FALSE
3 IndH 3 3                                                                FALSE
4 IndI 1 1                                                                FALSE
5 IndJ 4 1                                                                 TRUE
6 IndK 3 5                                                                FALSE
>
```

Comment: Thanks !! The question only remaining to the solution is that each time I need to create dumatchXXX for each P1 and P2 pair...I would love to try to create universal dum.match creater solution, as I have many P1 and P2 pairs..which automatically looks the p1 and p2 to do so....thanks for the response appreciated